# Python WebDriverException: 'chromedriver.exe' executable needs to be in PATH. Please see https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/home

Tags: selenium, google-chrome

There is a program that schools implement every day to prevent corona.
I'm going to make a macro using Selenium.
However, it cannot be executed due to the above error. I would appreciate it if you could suggest a solution.

Error : WebDriverException: 'chromedriver' executable needs to be in PATH. Please see https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/home

code content

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome('chromedriver')

driver.implicitly_wait(3)  

driver.get('https://hcs.eduro.go.kr/#/relogin')
```

Comment: driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r'C:\path\to\chromedriver.exe') but fill in your full path to the chrome driver executable